# How to publish Int16MultiArray from command line?

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a C++ subscriber that listens for a message composed of a two integers, which I've implemented with a `std_msgs::Int16MultiArray` message type like:

```
void on_motor_speed(const std_msgs::Int16MultiArray& msg){
    ///do stuff
}
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int16MultiArray> motor_speed_sub("motor/speed", &on_motor_speed);
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

How do I test this from the command line using `rostopic pub`? Based on [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/189073/rostopic-pub-multiarray/), I think is should be something like:

```
rostopic pub motor/speed std_msgs/Int16MultiArray "{layout:{dim:[{label:'', size:0, stride:0}], data_offset:0}, data:[64, 64]}"
```

but I get the YAML parsing error:

```
Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

rostopic: error: Argument error: while scanning a plain scalar
  in "<string>", line 1, column 16:
    {layout:{dim:[{label:'', size:0, stride:0}], da ... 
                   ^
found unexpected ':'
  in "<string>", line 1, column 21:
    {layout:{dim:[{label:'', size:0, stride:0}], data_of ... 
                        ^
Please check http://pyyaml.org/wiki/YAMLColonInFlowContext for details.
```

As far as I know, YAML does support the inline syntax, and doesn't need to be multi-line. What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257913/how-to-publish-int16multiarray-from-command-line?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It says right in the error what went wrong.

```
rostopic: error: Argument error: while scanning a plain scalar
  in "<string>", line 1, column 16:
    {layout:{dim:[{label:'', size:0, stride:0}], da ... 
                   ^
found unexpected ':'
  in "<string>", line 1, column 21:
    {layout:{dim:[{label:'', size:0, stride:0}], data_of ...
```

This is saying that you need put a space between the colon `:` and the value. What you should be typing is this:

```
rostopic pub motor/speed std_msgs/Int16MultiArray "{layout: {dim: [{label: '', size: 0, stride: 0}], data_offset: 0}, data: [64, 64]}"
```

A useful tip is that you should be using the tab autocomplete. If you use that, it will fill in the message with a nicely formatted YAML string like so:

```
$ rostopipub motor/speed std_msgs/Int16MultiArray "layout:
  dim:
  - label: ''
    size: 0
    stride: 0
  data_offset: 0
data:
- 0"
```

Then you can go into the string itself and enter your data.

Edit: I originally stated that single quotes were needed around the keys, this is actually incorrect.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2